# Gsub regex replacement

Tags: regex, r, replace, gsub

I am trying to do a gsub replacement in R.  I would like to identify two terms from two lists separated by a single whitespace and replace it with an underscore.  I have successfully identified the match but I am not experienced enough in regex to understand the gsub documentation. Can somebody help write the `gsub`?

Right now I have:

```
gsub("(a|b|c)\\s+(x|y|z)","(a|b|c)_(x|y|z)",a x)
```

(Note: there are several places in the string that match this if that matters)

I want to go from:
a x -> a_x 
b z -> b_z 
hello world b x how are a z you -> hello world b_x how are a_z you... and so on.

Instead it does:
a x -> (a|b|c)*(x|y|z) 

b z -> (a|b|c)*(x|y|z) ... and so on.

If anyone wants to drop a little theory in that would be appreciated but I'm working on a deadline so a simultaneous answer would be ideal.

Thanks.

Comment: It probably took you longer to write that question than it would have taken you to find the answer yourself through the `gsub` doc. It even has examples that use `\\1`, `\\2`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `\\1` and `\\2` to replace the term inside the first and second `()` with itself.

```
vec <- "hello world b x how are a z you"

gsub("(a|b|c)\\s+(x|y|z)","\\1_\\2", vec)
# [1] "hello world b_x how are a_z you"
```

Comment: Thanks. The documentation made it sound like the "\\1" was meant to refer to number of backspaces from some place.  How is the segmentation actually done? Is it just automatically space separated?

Comment: @user3030872 As I already mentioned in the answer, `\\1` is the string within the first `()`.